# Shell scripting redirecting a file

Tags: shell, file-io, grep, io-redirection

I have a dictionary file, in a text file. so i want to move all the letters that starts with A in a different file. So I grep the words, then I want to redirect the command using shell notation into a different file. How am i able to do that?

Like I want to move all the words that I have grepped into another file.

I don't seem to be able to do it, I keep on saving an empty file.

Comment: Why don't you try this operator-->  `>`!

Comment: Isn't redirection the second or third thing you learn when using the shell?

Comment: How can we tell what you're doing wrong if you don't post what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
grep -Pow 'A\w*' file > new_file
```

Add `-i` to make it case insensitive.

Comment: This solves the problem for a file of text, but is overtly complicated for what is probably a file with one word per line. Also, for a text file, how do you produce the complement, i.e. a file with only those words removed?

Comment: @tripleee It's only a start. I'm waiting for some clarified details from the OP actually.